# Creating Many to one relationships using array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

I am creating a teach the teacher program that should assign multiple and unique teachers to teach another teacher.

I am using an array of arrays to capture and randomize the groups and the list of teachers. In this script I am using 3 levels of arrays. Would this be inefficient for a long list and many groups?

```
    //Shuffle and create groups

    function shuffle(a) {
       for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
       [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
     }
      return a;
    }

    const Tgroups = [[3,[1, 2]], [4,[5,6]], [7,[8,9]],[10,[11,12]]];
   //const Tgroups = [[1, 2], [5,6], [8,9],[11,12]];

   Tgroups.forEach(shuffle);
   shuffle(Tgroups);

   console.log("shuffled:", Tgroups.join(" | "))


   const Tlist = [].concat(...Tgroups);

   console.log("Tlist:", Tlist);
```

I have been able to pair one teacher with another.

```
    // match the group with the list:
    const pairs = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < Math.floor(Tlist.length / 2); i++) {
    pairs.push([
    Tlist[i],
    Tlist[i + Math.floor(Tlist.length / 2)]
    ]);
   }

  if(Tlist.length % 2)
  pairs.push([Tlist.pop()]);
  console.log("pairs:", pairs.join(" | "));

  const result = [].concat(...pairs);
```

However, I do not believe I am creating the many to one relation using the following

```
    for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
     {
       var innerArrayLength = result[i].length;
       for (let j = 0; j < innerArrayLength; j++) 
     {
       //console.log('[' + i + ',' + j + '] = ' + result[i][j]);
       console.log(result[i] + " -> " + result[(i + 2) % result.length]);
     }
```

Please, is there a way to achieve a better result?

Comment: Can't you just use an object for each teacher, with an id indicating the teacher who will be teaching them? This will eliminate the need for a 3d array

Comment: @Kobe The teachers have to be selected and assigned at random and not predetermined.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make your code runnable:

```js
/* PART 1 */

//Shuffle and create groups
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

const Tgroups = [
  [3, [1, 2]],
  [4, [5, 6]],
  [7, [8, 9]],
  [10, [11, 12]]
];
//const Tgroups = [[1, 2], [5,6], [8,9],[11,12]];

Tgroups.forEach(shuffle);
shuffle(Tgroups);

console.log("shuffled:", Tgroups.join(" | "))


const Tlist = [].concat(...Tgroups);

console.log("Tlist:", Tlist);

/* PART 2 */

// match the group with the list:
const pairs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(Tlist.length / 2); i++) {
  pairs.push([
    Tlist[i],
    Tlist[i + Math.floor(Tlist.length / 2)]
  ]);
}

if (Tlist.length % 2)
  pairs.push([Tlist.pop()]);
console.log("pairs:", pairs.join(" | "));

const result = [].concat(...pairs);
console.log('result:', JSON.stringify(result));

/* PART 3 */

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var innerArrayLength = result[i].length;
  for (let j = 0; j < innerArrayLength; j++) {
    //console.log('[' + i + ',' + j + '] = ' + result[i][j]);
    console.log(result[i] + " -> " + result[(i + 2) % result.length]);
  }
}
```

So you have this array as input:

```js
[[3,[1, 2]], [4,[5,6]], [7,[8,9]],[10,[11,12]]]
```

And this array as output:

```js
[[1,2],[5,6],3,4,[8,9],10,7,[11,12]]
```

But you iterate it in a very strange way, so the actual output of `console.log` is:

```
1,2 -> 3
1,2 -> 3
5,6 -> 4
5,6 -> 4
8,9 -> 7
8,9 -> 7
11,12 -> 5,6
11,12 -> 5,6
```

What are you trying to achieve actually? It is hard to understand the task...

But on the first sight, you need to flatten first array, then shuffle the result and in this 2 steps you will come to desired output.

Let me try:

```js
const Tgroups = [[3, [1, 2]],[4, [5, 6]], [7, [8, 9]], [10, [11, 12]]];

const flatInput = Tgroups.flat(1);

function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

const result = shuffle(flatInput);

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var innerArrayLength = result[i].length;
  if (innerArrayLength) {
    console.log(result[i] + " -> " + result[(i + 2) % result.length]);
  }
}
```

So we have the same result with less code, but I do not understand what is happening here :|

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220596/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-creating-many-to-one-relationships-using-array-of).

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how it will look like for 100 people:

```js
const totalPeople = 100;

// based on comments, you know, that actually we will teach only half of the people
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < totalPeople / 2; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    result.push('' + (i * 2 + 1) + ',' + (i * 2 + 3) + '->' + (i + 2));
  else
    result.push('' + (i * 2) + ',' + (i * 2 + 2) + '->' + (i));
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```